# Meaning of the "@package" decorator in Python

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I'm trying to understand a class method definition which reads similar to the following:

```
@package(type='accounts', source='system')
def get(self, [other arguments]):
    [function body]
```

What is the meaning of the `@package` decorator? I was unable to find documentation on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no default `package` decorator in the Python standard library.

A decorator is *just a simple expression*; there will be a `package()` callable in the same module (either defined there as a function or class, or imported from another module).

The line `@package(type='accounts', source='system')` executes the expression `package(type='accounts', source='system')`, and the return value of that is used to decorate the `get()` function. You could read it as:

```
def get(self, [other arguments]):
    [function body]
get = package(type='accounts', source='system')(get)
```

except the name `get` is set just once.

For example, `package` could be defined as:

```
def package(type='foo', source='bar'):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            # do something with type and source
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

so `package()` returns `decorator()`, which in turn returns `wrapper()`; `package()` is a *decorator factory*, producing the actual decorator.

Comment: interesting use of a decorator factory +1